# Allow Multiple JARs to Access Same Classes

Tags: java, process, jar, classloader

I am working on a game which has three components: A launcher (to keep everything up to date and authenticate players), the game itself, and a server (which allows for multiplayer). All three of these use a few common classes (utilities, GUI themes, an XML library I wrote). The server and game are both started from the launcher, so can I put these classes in *only* the launcher and have the game and server be able to access them?

Right now, I'm loading the server and game by using a Process with `java -jar`.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the classpath for every JVM you launch.  In your case, I would separate common functionality (if you have not done so yet) into a single jar (say utils.jar) and make sure to include it in the classpath of every process.  For example:

```
-- Start the server
java -cp server.jar;utils.jar game.Server

-- Start the launcher
java -cp client.jar;launcher.jar;utils.jar game.Launcher
```

Does it fit your needs?

Comment: I have considered doing that, but my launcher keeps all components of the game up to date, and adding another JAR would just bloat it a little bit more. Also, I'd have to make the launcher update the utils JAR before launch, which would complicate it further. If no one comes up with a better answer, I'll take this route.

Comment: Have you written your own solution to keep everything up to date?  Did you consider Web Start?  It could maybe be useful.  http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml

Comment: I host my content as well as version information on a website. The launcher checks remote version information against the local version information. If it finds a change, it'll download the latest version of whatever's new from the site. I also host the changelog on the site, and the launcher displays it.